# How to exclude sub package in pointcut expression in spring AOP

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I have searched on it but didnt get my required answer about including scan base package and excluding a sub package.

eg: project structure

```
MyTest
--src/main/java
----com.spring
----com.spring.controller
----com.spring.entity
----com.spring.repository
----com.spring.service
----com.spring.service.dto
----com.spring.repo.dto
----com.spring.repo.dto.v2
----com.spring.service.dto.v2
----com.spring.service.pojo
```

I want to write a pointcut where I will scan base package `com.spring` and want to exclude `dto` sub package.

here is what I tried:

```
basePkg="com.spring";
"execution(* " + basePkg + ".service.*.*(..))" +  " && !execution(* *.dto.*(..))" ;
```

this is excluding dto but only scanning service pkg.
NB: I dont want to include all required pkg manually as there might be(actually is) numbers of pkgs in the project.

```
   "execution(* " + basePkg + "..*.*(..))" +  " && !execution(* *.dto.*(..))" ;
   "execution(* " + basePkg + "..*.*(..))" +  " && !execution(* " + basePkg + "..*.dto.*.*(..))"
```

above I scanned all package and tried excluding dto sub package...but its scanning all package no dto exclusion.

Here I need some guidance.

EDIT:

generally spring app has a base pkg and adding business in corresponding sub-pkgs. Here I gave com.spring. So I need all methods to be advised in its all sub pkgs AND if I want to exclude any sub pkg(com.spring.dto/com.spring.service.dto/com.spring.service.dto.v2/com.spring.repo.dto/com.spring.repo.dto.v2 etc) I should be able to exclude those as its all have dto sub-pkg common.

PLEASE refer my project pkg. I need a generic one to add or remove not individual sub to sub pkgs

Comment: Your question is somewhat imprecise, which is why you are debating with @itshagunrathore about his answer. Please explain **exactly** what you want, e.g. all of `com.spring..*` without `com.spring.service.dto..*` or just  `com.spring.service..*` without `com.spring.service.dto..*`. Either way, please note that `*.dto.*` is not the same as `*..dto..*`. The double-dot notation encompasses subpackages, the single-dot one does not. `*.dto.*` would match `x.foo.MyClass`, but neither `x.y.foo.MyClass` nor `x.foo.y.MyClass`.

Comment: I added few more points. Please refer MY project structure. Whatever itshagunrathore mentioned its correct as per itshagunrathore project structure which is different than mine.  I added another dto sub-pkg for ref...please check. if debating will end with a conclusion then its good :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your project structure

```
com.spring
 |- service
 |   |- Service.java
 |
 |- dto
 |   |- Dto.java
```

This is how you can exclude dto from the poincut

```
@Pointcut("within(com.spring.service..*) && !within(com.spring.service.dto..*)")
public void serviceMethodPointcut() {}
```

---

For the project structure above in the question

```
MyTest
--src/main/java
----com.spring
----com.spring.controller
----com.spring.entity
----com.spring.repository
----com.spring.service
----com.spring.service.dto
----com.spring.repo.dto
----com.spring.repo.dto.v2
----com.spring.service.dto.v2
----com.spring.service.pojo
```

This pointcut will work -

```
execution(* com.spring..*(..)) && within(com.spring..*) &&  !within(*..dto..*);
```

OR

```
within(com.spring..*) && !within(*..dto..*)
```

As, the above pointcut matches any method in com.spring package and its subpackages except the packages have dto in there name.

example of the method **matched** with the pointcut

```
com.spring.service.myservice.methodB()
com.spring.pojo.mypojo.methodA()
```

example of the method will **not be matched** with the pointcut

```
com.spring.service.dto.mydto.methodA()
com.spring.repo.dto.v2.methodA()
```

Comment: project structure is fixed(yes its not fully proper...but cant change now).Above pointcut will scan service pkg, I need all other pkgs as well but not manually adding it. So scanned base pkg. Above I tried and worked but now I want a generic expression like scan all sub pkgs of base pkg AND exclude some sub pkgs sitting anywhere in a long pkgs here dto.

Comment: Try using @Pointcut("within(com.spring..*) && !within(com.spring.service.dto..*)").

If you want to exclude multiple packages, use multiple !within separated with && .

eg - "within(com.spring..*) && !within(com.spring.service.dto..*) && !within(com.spring.service.dto.v2..*)

Comment: right but if dto sub pkg position changes eg: com.spring.service1.service2.dto, then again I need to change right....need generic one please.

Comment: Try one of these in your case... 
`execution(* *..*(..)) && !within(*..dto..*);` OR

`execution(* com.spring..*(..)) && within(com.spring..*) &&  !within(*..dto..*);` OR

`execution(* com.spring..*(..)) &&  !within(*..dto..*));`

Comment: The pointcut in this answer is correct, but the package structure is depicted falsely in the first code block, which is why @Joe seems to be confused. Please fix that. Like your pointcut correctly says, `dto` is a subpackage of `service`. In your answer it looks like a sibling. The pointcut should solve Joe's problem.

Comment: kriegaex: I modified a bit please check the project structure

Comment: After the OP edited the question, the solution needs to be more general, just like I suggested in my comment under the question. So `within(com.spring..*) && !within(*..dto..*)` is correct, as also suggested here in the updated answer. The `execution(* com.spring..*(..))` part can be simplified to `execution(* *(..))`, because the `within` clauses already determine the target packages. Actually, the `execution` part can be skipped for Spring AOP completely, it is only necessary for native AspectJ, because the latter has more pointcut types.

Comment: execution(* com.spring..*(..)) && within(com.spring..*) &&  !within(*..dto..*);...this gives some idea and enhanched it...Thanks..accepted
...only within not required as I needed full class.method info....